# Using Plotly with DT via crosstalk in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, dt

I am writing an app to read a csv file into shiny and link a plotly scatter plot with a DT table. I pretty much followed the example from the Plotly website on DT datatable (https://plot.ly/r/datatable/) with the exception that the saved data from the csv is saved as a reactive input and that I have selectinput for the x and y variables for the scatterplot. 
I can generate the plot and DT table after clicking on the action button and I can also update the DT to only show selected rows from brushing the scatterplot. My problem is that when I select rows in the DT, then the corresponding individual points in the scatterplot does not become selected (should be in red color). I seems to be that I used reactive functions() as input for the x and y variables instead of formulas in plotly but I cannot seem to overcome this problem.

A warning message appear on the console but I cant seem to figure out how to fix this:

Warning in origRenderFunc() :
  Ignoring explicitly provided widget ID "154870637775"; Shiny doesn't use them
Setting the `off` event (i.e., 'plotly_deselect') to match the `on` event (i.e., 'plotly_selected'). You can change this default via the `highlight()` function.

Would be thankful for any input on this issue.

I have simplified my shiny app to include only the relevant code chunks:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme('spacelab'),
  titlePanel("Plot"),
  tabsetPanel(

    # Upload Files Panel
    tabPanel("Upload File",
             titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                           accept=c('text/csv', 
                                    'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                    '.csv')),

                 tags$br(),

                 checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                 radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                              c(Comma=',',
                                Semicolon=';',
                                Tab='\t'),
                              ','),
                 radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                              c(None='',
                                'Double Quote'='"',
                                'Single Quote'="'"),
                              '"'),
                 # Horizontal line ----
                 tags$hr(),

                 # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
                 radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                              choices = c(Head = "head",
                                          All = "all"),
                              selected = "head")


               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput('contents')
               )
             )
    ),

    # Plot and DT Panel
    tabPanel("Plots",
             titlePanel("Plot and Datatable"),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput('xvar', 'X variable', ""),
                 selectInput("yvar", "Y variable", ""),
                 actionButton('go', 'Update')
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 plotlyOutput("Plot1"),
                 DT::dataTableOutput("Table1")
                 )
             )
    )
  )
)


# Server function ---------------------------------------------------------


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ## For uploading Files Panel ## 

  MD_data <- reactive({ 
    req(input$file1) ## ?req #  require that the input is available
    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath, 
                   header = input$header, 
                   sep = input$sep,
                   quote = input$quote)
    return(df)
  })


  # add a table of the file
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(MD_data())){return()}

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(MD_data()))
    }
    else {
      return(MD_data())
    }
  })



  #### Plot Panel ####

  observeEvent(input$go, {

    m <- MD_data ()



    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xvar', label = 'Specify the x variable for plot',
                      choices = names(m), selected = NULL)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'yvar', label = 'Specify the y variable for plot',
                      choices = names(m), selected = NULL)

    plot_x1 <- reactive({
      m[,input$xvar]})

    plot_y1 <- reactive({
      m[,input$yvar]})

    ########   
    d <- SharedData$new(m)


    # highlight selected rows in the scatterplot
    output$Plot1 <- renderPlotly({

      s <- input$Table1_rows_selected

      if (!length(s)) {
        p <- d %>%
          plot_ly(x = ~plot_x1(), y = ~plot_y1(), type = "scatter", mode = "markers", color = I('black'), name = 'Unfiltered') %>%
          layout(showlegend = T) %>% 
          highlight("plotly_selected", color = I('red'), selected = attrs_selected(name = 'Filtered'), deselected = attrs_selected(name ="Unfiltered)"))
      } else if (length(s)) {
        pp <- m %>%
          plot_ly() %>% 
          add_trace(x = ~plot_x1(), y = ~plot_y1(), type = "scatter", mode = "markers", color = I('black'), name = 'Unfiltered') %>%
          layout(showlegend = T)

        # selected data
        pp <- add_trace(pp, data = m[s, , drop = F], x = ~plot_x1(), y = ~plot_y1(), type = "scatter", mode = "markers",
                        color = I('red'), name = 'Filtered')
      }

    })

    # highlight selected rows in the table
    output$Table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      T_out1 <- m[d$selection(),]
      dt <- DT::datatable(m)
      if (NROW(T_out1) == 0) {
        dt
      } else {
        T_out1
        }
    })


    }) 



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a sharedData object so that both Plotly and DT can share updated selections. Hopefully my toy example below can help illustrate. Unfortunately, I have not found a way of making crosstalk work with imported files (my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349881/how-to-use-crosstalk-in-shiny-when-shareddata-refers-to-a-file-not-yet-loaded) refers).

```
library(shiny)
library(crosstalk)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

# Shared data available for use by the crosstalk package
shared_df <- SharedData$new(iris)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Crosstalk test"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      filter_select("iris-select", "Select Species:",
                    shared_df,
                    ~Species),
      filter_slider("iris-slider", "Select width:",
                    shared_df,
                    ~Sepal.Width, step=0.1, width=250)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated data
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("distPlot"),
      DTOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(ggplot(shared_df) +
      geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, colour = Species))
    )
  })

  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(shared_df, extensions="Scroller", style="bootstrap", class="compact", width="100%",
              options=list(deferRender=TRUE, scrollY=300, scroller=TRUE))
  }, server = FALSE)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks RDavey. It is similar but not quite what I wanted with my question. I already ahve a SharedData object. My colleague found out that the pp object needs to be subsetted and it worked by changing to following:  ` # selected data
        pp <- add_trace(pp, data = m[s, , drop = F], 
                        x = ~plot_x1()[s], 
                        y = ~plot_y1()[s], 
                        type = "scatter", 
                        mode = "markers",
                        color = I('red'), 
                        name = 'Filtered')`.

Comment: Now I have the problem that when I brush select data point the datatable will update accordingly but selecting a row in the newly updated datatable will not refer to correct data point in the plot but refer to the original unfiltered data.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to solve this, but maybe using DataTableProxy("table") to refer to changes could help. Also, if you don't mind updating the datatable then you might be able to use my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54426548/how-to-edit-a-table-using-dt-and-shiny-from-an-uploaded-file/54443204#54443204), which relies on the input$table_cell_edit event.