# Is it possibe to detect which datapoint is highlighted on plotly scatter plot?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, scatter-plot

In the scatter plot popout we can choose which column data you want to display on hover. But if I want to see all the columns the popout will be very long. Is there any way I can show the select data point in a datatable? Basically I want to detect which data point is hovered on.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765687/return-datapoints-selected-in-a-plotly-scatterplot

Comment: Try `plotly_clicked` or `plotly_selected` from the [`event_data` function (17.2)](https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html)